# Co-located Markers On Maps - C# Web Application

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am developing a web application that uses the Google Maps API.

When plotting markers on the exact same spot on the map they just hide / overlap each other.

Is there any functionality that can deal with co-located markers more effectively OR any external add-ons available to deal with co-located markers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to see different markers at the exact same location, you have to use [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier)

You can take a look to the [demo page](http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html)

If you need the Spiderfier be fired only when multiple markers are at the **exact** same location, you'll have to define the `nearbyDistance` to `0` in the options. Just take a look to the doc I linked above